# Do shortcut operators work in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

In MATLAB, if you type `if (a)&&(b)`, then `b` isn't tested if `a` is false.  This is really handy for cases where the second condition would throw an error if the first condition isn't true.

In Objective C, this doesn't appear to be the case.  So, my question is:  are there any similar ways to have ordered conditions in an if statement?  Or must the two statements simple be nested? (E.g., `if (a){ if(b) {`.)

Thanks for reading.

Comment: How does it not appear to be the case???

Comment: (Keep in mind that in Objective-C if you make a method call on a nil pointer it returns zero/nil.  This can make one believe that an object pointer is valid when it is not, and hence leads to all sorts of incorrect conclusions.)

Comment: OK, here was my issue:  I had been using a bitwise AND operator (&) and not the proper logical AND operator (&&).  Now all is good.  Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In Objective C, this doesn't appear to be the case.

This is incorrect. C and its derivatives, including C++ and Objective-C, follow the same short-circuiting rules that you're familiar with from Matlab. In an expression of the form:

```
x && y
```

`y` will not be evaluated if `x` is false.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  My problem was that I had been using "&" as my AND in Objective C instead of &&.  Problem solved!